# When will the next LTS version of Lubuntu be released?

Tags: lubuntu, lts

12.04 was an LTS for Ubuntu but not for Lubuntu, hence this query.

Comment: I think this is a relevant Q: [Does 12.04 LXDE have LTS?](http://askubuntu.com/q/237077/88802)

Answer (score 8):

"Please note that Lubuntu 12.04 is not an LTS (5 years support), but a 'standard' release, supported for 18 months. This is simply due the fact there is insufficient 'man-power' to commit to 5 years of support."

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu

---

There is a *possibility* of LTS for Lubuntu 14.04: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/lubuntu-users/2013-April/003941.html

> Next steps are 13.10, and 14.04 which should be a LTS version for
>   Ubuntu. Last LTS (12.04), I considered that we were not ready for such
>   commitment. I was also unsure of the work needed to make a good LTS.
>   With more experience, I have now a better vision of this goal.
>
> So, let's make it simple, I would like Lubuntu 14.04 to be a LTS
>   version.
>
> But claiming we want a LTS its' not enough. First, we need to make it
>   stable enough, so we can safely claim it's a LTS, because people who
>   install a LTS want a stable system. But, I also would like to make it
>   sexy enough to be proud of it, to make people happy to recommend it. I
>   would like to make it THE release of Lubuntu, the reference of all
>   Lubuntu releases. To achieve it, I have several goals in mind, items
>   that I consider we need to finish for the LTS, and I think we can
>   finish them ...

---

Read more about Lubuntu's future here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu/Testing/14.04