# Ubuntu has LTS and normal version now. Does Lubuntu have the same?

Tags: lubuntu, lts

Anyway....there is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and the normal 12.10 version. Is that the same with Lubuntu? On their site, for some reason, they seem to be promoting the 12.10 version while for me an LTS is always more appealing. I am wondering if they have the same ideology as the Ubuntu team.

**UPDATE:** Is it okay to talk about Lubuntu here at all? I understand that it is a flavour of Ubuntu...but still. Are they 2 very different teams?

Comment: Similar question? http://askubuntu.com/questions/202844/when-will-the-next-lts-version-of-lubuntu-be-released?rq=1 i.e. 12.04 is not an LTS release.

Comment: @fossfreedom, maybe the question is being repeated because no answer in the similar question was upvoted, let alone accepted?

Comment: @Elysium - yes lubuntu questions are welcome here on AskUbuntu - indeed - encouraged.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Foss, I have just commented on the answer below. Can you have a look at that message? I'd really like to understand this issue (well, issue for me :))

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you use the 'regular' Ubuntu 12.04 as base, and want to install LXDE after installation?

Comment: @GerhardBurger This is of no interest - see the bottom part of [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/237087/88802).

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): [Does 12.04 LXDE have LTS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/237077/does-12-04-lxde-have-lts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

> Unlike Ubuntu, Lubuntu 12.04 is not a LTS, this version will be supported for 18 months. However, a lot of work has been done to improve the stability of the system.

[Source](http://lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-1204-now-available)

Note: Lubuntu 12.04 is not LTS, but it's based on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. So it's very stable, the same way as Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I'd like to recommend to you to upgrade your system to Lubuntu 12.10.

You can check the differences of Lubuntu 12.10 to Lubuntu 12.04 at this [link](http://lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-1210-now-available).

Comment: but this means that in the case of Lubuntu, it is not the idea of whether it is a normal or LTS version, but the idea of getting the latest version...which is the 12.10 version in this case. Since they simply work on making one version as stable as possible and that's it. Am I correct?

Comment: @Elysium Yes, you're correct.

Comment: @Elysium Kubuntu 12.04 is also an LTS, and so is Xubuntu, Mythbuntu and Ubuntu Studio. Lubuntu just didn't make it, or so it seems.

Comment: I'd like to try LXDE. So far that seems to be the most promising option for me. I am done with unity and gnome. This is why I am asking about Lubuntu. :)

Comment: @Elysium I have to tell you that the modification made on LXDE on Lubuntu 12.10 made it get more beautiful than the original LXDE and more than Xfce on Xubuntu too.

Comment: @Zignd Perfect. I hope that is true about its usability too. I already have the install disc. I'll give it a go now in the VM.

Comment: @Elysium After installation test one of the most awesome features of Lubuntu, use the roll scroll wheel up/down to maximize/minimize the window with that you will never want to click to maximize/minimize a window and if you use it at the title bar of the window another interesting things happens. After testing these feature for the first time you will get addicted to it and will hate to use Windows. ;)

Comment: alrighty. :) Depending on my time, I'll try it soon and let you know. :) What is the feature called? I'd like to read a bit about it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it have a name. But you don't need to activate it as it's integrated with the system.

Please don't forget to accept my answer as the correct. :)

Enjoy Lubuntu (LXDE + Ubuntu)!!!

Comment: zignd ,  thanks. I have just accepted ur answer. by the way, I ended up using mint 14 mate. I like it a lot. :)

Comment: [lubuntu.me is the official site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029381/which-lubuntu-website-is-the-correct-one) and [now seems they have LTS releases](https://lubuntu.me/bionic-released/)

Answer (score 20):

No, but also yes. You will receive 5 years support on packages Ubuntu provides support for this term.

Lubuntu shares packages with Ubuntu in a sense that "underlying" "base" software like Alsa, the kernel, common shared libraries and such are from the same archive and maintained by the same people. Lubuntu is nothing more than Ubuntu with another set of preselected set of packages. It's just that Unity comes with 5 years of support and LXDE doesn't, in Ubuntu.

For the example of the kernel, Unity and LXDE core, run this on Lubuntu 12.04 or Ubuntu 12.04 (won't make a difference):

```
$ apt-cache show linux-image-generic | grep ^Supported
Supported: 5y

$ apt-cache show unity | grep ^Supported
Supported: 5y

$ apt-cache show lxde-core | grep ^Supported
<no output>
```

This way, you can check for every package whether it comes with the 5 years of support or not.

---

So, this makes me disagree with [the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/237085/88802) stating

> Also, please note that if you are using Lubuntu, instead of Ubuntu, you will not receive LTS since Lubuntu 12.04 isn't an LTS release.

Because, *regardless* of *how* you installed Lubuntu<sup>1</sup>, you will receive updates for 5 years, yet not for all of your packages (including LXDE).

<sup>1</sup> <sub>You can install Lubuntu in two ways. 1) Install regular Ubuntu first, replacing Unity with LXDE via the `lubuntu-desktop^` [apt-task](https://askubuntu.com/a/257172/88802) and selecting it in your login screen as desktop environment to log in to, or 2) using the Lubunu Live CD/installer directly.</sub>

Comment: [_Lubuntu used to use LXDE as its default desktop environment_](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours). Now it use LXQt, sow now should we `apt-cache show lxqt-core | grep ^Supported`? [Seems they have LTS releases](https://lubuntu.me/bionic-released/), even [from 14.04](https://lubuntu.me/lubuntu-14043-lts/)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.
You will still receive security updates for your Ubuntu machine if you are using Long Term Support (LTS). However, *not all* applications will receive security updates since the LTS designation only applies to certain parts of the Ubuntu Archive.

Also, please note that **if you are using Lubuntu**, instead of Ubuntu, **you will not** receive LTS since [Lubuntu 12.04 isn't an LTS release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu#Lubuntu_12.04_is_not_an_LTS).

Examples of applications that may receive security updates are those which are supported by the Ubuntu Team or Canonical such as Ubuntu One or Firefox.

Source: An explanation of LTS in the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want a bloatware of packages and software on your machine, just install Lubuntu 12.04, but again it's not LTS. To get this "LTS" version of Lubuntu, you have to install Ubuntu 12.04 and then open the terminal and install:

`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

But again, you still have a bloatware of packages that came with Unity and Ubuntu-desktop and you need to purge a lot of stuff to get pure Lubuntu desktop and you should be careful when doing this. And another thing is, you gonna using unity greeter lightdm instead of the lubuntu lightdm version.

Comment: The packages that don't have long-term support when you install Lubuntu normally don't have long-term support when you install them  as dependencies of `lubuntu-desktop` either.

Comment: I agree with Eliah here. I think your answer is wrong and moreover, it was already (completely) covered in the other two answers (one of them by me). If you think I am wrong on this, please use a comment to respond to it, thanks! (although this may only be possible once you've gained enough reputation on this site)