# Which Lubuntu website is the correct one?

Tags: lubuntu

There are two totally different websites offering Lubuntu:

https://lubuntu.net

https://lubuntu.me

What is their difference?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The official Lubuntu home is: https://lubuntu.me

If you query whois you see that lubuntu.me is registered by Canonical:

```
$ whois lubuntu.me
[..]
Registrant Organization: Canonical, Ltd.
[..]
```

Also, some Canonical owned pages about Lubuntu stuff link to lubuntu.me:

- the Ubuntu release page: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/
- the Ubuntu flavors page: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours
- a 2016 request to update some links to lubuntu.me: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-website-content/+bug/1543842

Last, but not least the Lubuntu Wikipedia page links to lubuntu.me as the official website: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu

On the other hand, you can find [frequent](https://www.reddit.com/r/Lubuntu/comments/4gnl1f/lubuntume_vs_lubuntunet_whats_happening/) [reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lubuntu-artwork/+bug/1608306/comments/1) about lubuntu.net having outdated download information and its whois is rather opaque: 'Admin Organization: WhoisGuard, Inc./Admin City: Panama'.

lubuntu.net is still around and apparently was maintained by a member of the lubuntu project. Since 2016, there seems to be some kind of beef going between the people then controlling lubuntu.net and the current lubuntu development team controlling lubuntu.me:

- 2016 launchpad discussion about lubuntu.me vs. lubuntu.net: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lubuntu-artwork/+bug/1608306 - in 2016 a lubuntu developer [commented](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lubuntu-artwork/+bug/1608306/comments/2) there 'Lubuntu.me is our official site, and we are working right now to talk to the owner of lubuntu.net in hopes of getting something done. I'll keep you posted.' and then [in 2018](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lubuntu-artwork/+bug/1608306/comments/27) 'Lubuntu.me is the only official and accurate one.'
- a [2018, April lubuntu.me blogpost](https://lubuntu.me/this-week-in-lubuntu-development-1/): 'all of our official web presences (meaning, Lubuntu.me and subdomains, because Lubuntu.net is no longer under the control of the Lubuntu project (we can’t say more at this time except that we are in no way affiliated with FOSSASIA))'
- a 2018, September [IRC comment](https://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2018/09/02/%23lubuntu.html) by one of the lubuntu developers 'They [lubuntu.net] refuse to publish up-to-date content and refuse to work with us.'
- a [lubuntu.me Phabricator ticket](https://web.archive.org/web/20180902091928/https://phab.lubuntu.me/F8209) asserting that lubuntu.net is 'impersonating' elements/pages of lubuntu.me

Comment: I will make this the current accepted answer because this recent information is very important for other people.

Comment: Quite a story...
See Linux User and Developer 192 p.9 May 24, 2018
https://issuu.com/futurepublishing/docs/lud192.issuu Hard to say what really happened. Why did GitHub uphold claim that FOSSAsia infringed Ubuntu trademarks and the GPL license and removed lubunu-dev from GitHub? Looks like it's a legal dispute between Canonical and FOSSAsia now. 

Answer (score 14):

Because Lubuntu was founded by Mario Behling and has been grown for many years by Julien Lavergne their web site still exists.  The official Canonical website is https://lubuntu.me and theirs is https://Lubuntu.net  There are those of us that used Lubuntu before it became officially recognized by Canonical as an officially supported "flavor".  That is why the two exist.

Answer (score 2):

[Ubuntu's official website](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours) and [DistroWatch](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=Lubuntu) both list http://lubuntu.me as the official website. Not exactly sure why there's two different websites.

Comment: Strange logic. DistroWatch is respectful, but third-party site. Why you do not refer official [Ubuntu Flavors](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/flavours) or [UbuntuFlavors wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFlavors) page? Both linked to http://lubuntu.me/ .

Comment: It is unfortunate that two sites exist, which can confuse people, but there is at least one reassuring fact: As of Sept 2019, the download links from lubuntu.net eventually points to ubuntu.com official site.

Comment: @WirawanPurwanto As of Mar 2021, lubuntu.net's most recent versions are 18.04 (32-bit) and 19.10 (64-bit), the latter of which has a broken download link. This was enough to make me think the project was dead until I discovered this stack exchange topic! Especially as Googlling "Lubuntu" reterns lubuntu.net as the first two results.