# Which LUbuntu comes with the Atomic Pi?

Tags: lubuntu

I was confused about the two LUbuntu sites, and then found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029381/which-lubuntu-website-is-the-correct-one).

On Reddit, I see that people often use 19.04, which doesn't seem available on LUbuntu.me, only LUbuntu.net.

How are the OS's on the two sites differentiated?  Which one originally came on the Atomic Pi?  If I cross the streams while trying to upgrade, will something bad happen?

Comment: It looks as though both downloads of 19.10 from lubuntu.me or from lubuntu.net are the same.  If you download the ISO files for 19.10 their md5sum should match from [this md5sum](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/eoan/release/MD5SUMS).  People are probably often using 19.04 since it has been out since April of 2019.  However, (L)ubuntu 19.04 will be going EOL in January of 2020 and will no longer be supported, hence the push to get people to upgrade to 19.10 before their 19.04 goes EOL.

Answer (score 0):

`lubuntu.net` is one of many '*fan*' sites which are not related to Ubuntu, or Lubuntu teams.   They do provide their own downloads, however most of their downloads do point to official ubuntu servers so it's on you to verify it's an *official* download (*and not something else as it's not an official site*).

If you use google.com to look for sites; you'll often find the *fan* sites listing above official sites, and the site at the top will most likely be one that uses your own language (the official site is really english based, so it's more noticable if you don't use english and a fan site is available in your own tongue).

If you don't know which is the official site, I'd suggest going to **ubuntu.com** and looking there. You'll end up at https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours which will point you to the official Ubuntu flavor site.

For Lubuntu it's http://lubuntu.me/

I'd trust the site which is controlled by the Lubuntu team, and monitored by Ubuntu, as against alternate sites which are not.

FYI:  *Lubuntu isn't trying to encourage Lubuntu 19.04 installs at this very late stage of it's life, it's EOL is approaching very fast, so why would you want to install an OS that reaches EOL in a few weeks?*  (https://lubuntu.me/disco-released/, http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/04/19/ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo-released/ EOL = end 18-Jan-2020)