# What are the differences between the versions on lubuntu download page?

Tags: lubuntu, software-recommendation, 64-bit

I can see these options on the lubuntu download page:

- lubuntu Desktop 32-bit/64-bit
- lubuntu Desktop PowerPC
- lubuntu Alternate 32-bit/64-bit
- lubuntu Alternate PowerPC

I need to install lubuntu on four different laptops and one PC, and I need to know difference between the versions. I'd rather not make a mistake installing wrong version and then have to reinstall it five times.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Lubuntu web site (https://lubuntu.me/downloads/) has available

- Desktop 64-bit (amd64)
- Desktop 32-bit (x86 also called i386)
- Desktop Alternate (x86 & amd64)
- Raspberry Pi (model 2 & 3)

Available firstly is the current Lubuntu 18.04 LTS using LXDE desktop, or legacy Lubuntu. The standard (32-bit & 64-bit) desktop use the standard Ubuntu `ubiquity` installer, the alternate installer uses *debian-installer*.

The ubiquity installer runs on a 'live' system, which requires ~700MB just for the live PLUS the memory required for the installer (so total is ~1gb)

The alternate installer has NO live system, thus is useful for machines with <700MB of ram.  Note: The alternate installer was last created for 18.04 (*not later* 18.04.1-18.04.3) so will require loads of updates post or during install. Live installers are available with 18.04.3 (*currently the latest*).

The original 18.04 & 18.04.1 do not include HWE kernel (hardware enablement stack - see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), the 18.04.2 & 18.04.3 have HWE enabled turned on, meaning later kernel & software stacks useful for more modern hardware.

Modern Lubuntu 19.10 uses the LXQt desktop and is only available in amd64 (or x86_64).  It's called *amd64* because AMD created the 64-bit architecture used by both AMD and INTEL (*Intel's competing IA64 failed in the marketplace due to lack of backward compatibility*)

Also available is the Raspberry Pi 2 & 3.

*I don't see PowerPC - were you looking at the Official Lubuntu web site?   If you're unsure, don't use google (it could send you to a 'fan' site), but use ubuntu.com where https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours will go to official sites for different flavors*.

*The x86 (32-bit), amd64 (x86_64), armv(7 & 8), arm64, s390, powerpc, ppc64el are different architectures.  Most PCs are amd64 today; powerpc is EOL being replaced by ppc64el (ppc 64-bit) which is incompatible*

**Lubuntu 18.04 LTS choice (Notes)**

- It's a LTS or long-term-support release, supported until 2021-April (3 years from release in 2018-April)
- LXDE is light & fast, but uses old GTK+2 which most modern applications haven't used in years, so some of lightness maybe lost when apps are added
- traditional desktop known & loved by many users
- LXDE is mostly abandoned, or on *life-support*, few updates
- will likely require re-install to move to modern Lubuntu with LXQt (*currently unsupported upgrade, this may change but I suspect not*)
- x86 and amd64 support  (ie. 32-bit)

**Lubuntu 19.10 choice (Notes)**

- a short term release, supported until 2020-July only
- has upgrade path to Lubuntu 20.04 LTS
- now amd64 only  (no 32-bit x86/i386)
- is very light; I tested 18.10 & 19.04 on x86 laptops with only 1GB of RAM & was happy
- has manual available http://manual.lubuntu.me/
- more modern LXQt desktop
- Some members of the Lubuntu team are more interested in LXQt & supporting it (*rather subjective opinion*)
- uses modern Qt5 framework, so does mean KDE or Qt apps will be lighter; alas modern GTK+3 apps won't be as light, but they weren't always real light on LXDE with it's GTK+2 desktop anyway
- better modern GTK3 & Qt theme support

Comment: I  was looking here: https://lubuntu.net/downloads/ Is that a fake site, or a clone?

Comment: It's a "*fan*" site.  If you look up who owns lubuntu.me you'll note it's Canonical, the company behind Ubuntu.  Lubuntu.net is not related to Ubuntu nor Lubuntu - but was operated by prior Lubuntu members I believe, but I don't really know.

Comment: The following maybe helpful for lubuntu.net - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029381/which-lubuntu-website-is-the-correct-one

Comment: Thank you very much for all the info.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica  I've added more detail on 18.04/19.10 choice...   If you look at lubuntu.me you'll find many resources available for Lubuntu, from manual (Modern LXQt only), discourse  & more..