# lubuntu.net vs lubuntu.me?

Tags: lubuntu

Whenever I google for Lubuntu, lubuntu.net is always appear on the top result. I thought that this was the official site (wasn't sure about this).

https://www.google.com/search?q=download+lubuntu

[image]

However, I've just noticed that there are two sites for Lubuntu.

lubuntu.net vs lubuntu.me

https://lubuntu.net/downloads/ only offers older version 19.04

while

https://lubuntu.me/downloads/ offers latest version which is 20.10.

Are they from similar or different team?

Which one is the official site for Lubuntu?

Comment: It looks like the first one is obsolete.

Comment: Looks kind of obvious to me, but the official one is lubuntu.me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which Lubuntu website is the correct one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029381/which-lubuntu-website-is-the-correct-one)

Comment: If you're not sure, don't ask google (unless you can evaluate its answers & know which is legitimate, *fan* or fake).  Ask Ubuntu.com (ie. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours will take you to official sites, as they're all kept under Canonical control with access only to *flavor* team members).  In that case it'll take you to lubuntu.me (fyi: Canonical is the company, who along with the Ubuntu Community stand behind Ubuntu).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://lubuntu.me/ is the official one. whois lookup will tell you the answer.

It was registerd by [Canonical, Ltd.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_(company)) which is the same company for Ubuntu.

```
$ whois -H lubuntu.me
Domain Name: LUBUNTU.ME
Registry Domain ID: D108500000015750671-AGRS
Registrar WHOIS Server:
Registrar URL: http://www.markmonitor.com
Updated Date: 2020-03-13T09:04:11Z
Creation Date: 2015-04-14T20:28:56Z
Registry Expiry Date: 2022-04-14T20:28:56Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date:
Registrar: MarkMonitor Inc.
Registrar IANA ID: 292
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abusecomplaints@markmonitor.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.2083895740
Reseller:
Domain Status: clientDeleteProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientDeleteProhibited
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Domain Status: clientUpdateProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientUpdateProhibited
Registrant Organization: Canonical, Ltd.
Registrant State/Province: Isle of Man
Registrant Country: GB
Name Server: NS2.CANONICAL.COM
Name Server: NS1.CANONICAL.COM
Name Server: NS3.CANONICAL.COM
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2020-12-04T14:49:36Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

$
```

lubuntu.net

```
$ whois -H lubuntu.net
   Domain Name: LUBUNTU.NET
   Registry Domain ID: 1535773036_DOMAIN_NET-VRSN
   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.namecheap.com
   Registrar URL: http://www.namecheap.com
   Updated Date: 2019-11-18T01:37:07Z
   Creation Date: 2009-01-02T12:07:37Z
   Registry Expiry Date: 2022-01-02T12:07:37Z
   Registrar: NameCheap, Inc.
   Registrar IANA ID: 1068
   Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@namecheap.com
   Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.6613102107
   Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Name Server: ARAGORN.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM
   Name Server: ELINORE.NS.CLOUDFLARE.COM
   DNSSEC: unsigned
   URL of the ICANN Whois Inaccuracy Complaint Form: https://www.icann.org/wicf/
>>> Last update of whois database: 2020-12-04T14:51:03Z <<<

For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp

NOTICE: The expiration date displayed in this record is the date the
registrar's sponsorship of the domain name registration in the registry is
currently set to expire. This date does not necessarily reflect the expiration
date of the domain name registrant's agreement with the sponsoring
registrar.  Users may consult the sponsoring registrar's Whois database to
view the registrar's reported date of expiration for this registration.

Domain name: lubuntu.net
Registry Domain ID: 1535773036_DOMAIN_NET-VRSN
Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.namecheap.com
Registrar URL: http://www.namecheap.com
Updated Date: 2019-11-18T01:37:07.36Z
Creation Date: 2009-01-02T12:07:37.00Z
Registrar Registration Expiration Date: 2022-01-02T12:07:37.00Z
Registrar: NAMECHEAP INC
Registrar IANA ID: 1068
Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@namecheap.com
Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: +1.6613102107
Reseller: NAMECHEAP INC
Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Registry Registrant ID: 
Registrant Name: WhoisGuard Protected
Registrant Organization: WhoisGuard, Inc.
Registrant Street: P.O. Box 0823-03411 
Registrant City: Panama
Registrant State/Province: Panama
Registrant Postal Code: 
Registrant Country: PA
Registrant Phone: +507.8365503
Registrant Phone Ext: 
Registrant Fax: +51.17057182
Registrant Fax Ext: 
Registrant Email: ea4b35f33e7945488e4d7442abca9088.protect@whoisguard.com
Registry Admin ID: 
Admin Name: WhoisGuard Protected
Admin Organization: WhoisGuard, Inc.
Admin Street: P.O. Box 0823-03411 
Admin City: Panama
Admin State/Province: Panama
Admin Postal Code: 
Admin Country: PA
Admin Phone: +507.8365503
Admin Phone Ext: 
Admin Fax: +51.17057182
Admin Fax Ext: 
Admin Email: ea4b35f33e7945488e4d7442abca9088.protect@whoisguard.com
Registry Tech ID: 
Tech Name: WhoisGuard Protected
Tech Organization: WhoisGuard, Inc.
Tech Street: P.O. Box 0823-03411 
Tech City: Panama
Tech State/Province: Panama
Tech Postal Code: 
Tech Country: PA
Tech Phone: +507.8365503
Tech Phone Ext: 
Tech Fax: +51.17057182
Tech Fax Ext: 
Tech Email: ea4b35f33e7945488e4d7442abca9088.protect@whoisguard.com
Name Server: elinore.ns.cloudflare.com
Name Server: aragorn.ns.cloudflare.com
DNSSEC: unsigned
URL of the ICANN WHOIS Data Problem Reporting System: http://wdprs.internic.net/
>>> Last update of WHOIS database: 2020-12-04T09:51:19.89Z <<<
For more information on Whois status codes, please visit https://icann.org/epp
$
```