# Does 12.04 LXDE have LTS?

Tags: lubuntu, lts

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202844/when-will-the-next-lts-version-of-lubuntu-be-released) sparked my question.

Will my PC receive the Long Term Support (LTS) using LXDE in Ubuntu 12.04?

What does it mean that [Lubuntu doesn't have long term support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lubuntu#Lubuntu_12.04_is_not_an_LTS)? Does it just mean it's not explicitly tested with new hardware and doesn't get point releases? Or does it mean that LXDE packages don't get the same kind of community support as community-supported packages that more commonly appear in Ubuntu installations?