# Is phpmyadmin 4.6.6 from bionic universe repository secure?

Tags: apt, server, 18.04, security, phpmyadmin

When installing phpmyadmin from the bionic universe repository I get version 4.6.6:

```
# apt show phpmyadmin
Package: phpmyadmin
Version: 4:4.6.6-5
Priority: extra
Section: universe/web
Origin: Ubuntu
…
```

On the [phpmyadmin website](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/news/2017/1/23/phpmyadmin-466-441510-and-401019-are-released/) I see that this version is nearly two years old now. Since then, many security fixes have been released. The current stable release is version 4.8.4.

I would favour to install phpmyadmin from the ubuntu repositories because I do dist-upgrades on a regular basis in the hope to maintain a secure system. But can it be considered secure to use this old version provided by the universe repository?

Is there maybe an alternative repository from which I could get newer versions when doing dist-upgrades?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/331473/security-updates-for-the-universe-repository-for-lts-releases

Comment: @RoVo thanks for the link, that is interesting to know. I wonder why the  phpMyAdmin Project guys don't maintain their software as a Debian/Ubuntu package like described above.